# Issue decoding EXR images compressed with DWAB using Imagemagick

Tags: ffmpeg

I've created an image sequence by converting PNG images to EXR using ImageMagick 7.1.1.
If I compress them using PIZ, ffmpeg 5.1.4 can read them well and convert the sequence to a video format.
If I compress them using DWAB, I get `[exr @ 0x1a80240] decode_block() failed.` errors.

It seemed to me that ffmpeg 5.1.4 was able to decode DWAB compressed EXR files.
Am I mistaken?

Comment: Is there any reason you do not use directly `PNG` to make video?

Comment: PNG files are much bigger (~x4 total size compared to DWAB EXR). And I tend to keep the image sequences as masters, so the smaller they are the better.